# How can I improve the speed of my code?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

```
A = 10;
a1 = 1.8;
h1 = 0.4;
b1 = 0.8;
d1 = 2900;
L1 = 0.05;
σ1 = 500;
k = 0.001;
n = 4;

c1[T_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {3, 0 < d1*T <= 100}, 
    {2, 100 < d1*T <= 200}, 
    {1,200 < d1*T <= 300}, 
    {0.5, 300 < d1*T}, 
    {0.5, True}}];

TCJS[T_, k_] := 
  A/T + c1[T]*d1*T + h1*((d1*T)/2 + k*σ1*Sqrt[T + 1]) + 
    (b1/T)*σ1*Sqrt[T + L1]*
      (PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - 
        k*Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y], {y, k, Infinity}]); 

EQ1[T_] := 
  (k*σ1*h1)/(2*Sqrt[T + L1]) - ((b1*σ1)/2)*
    (PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - 
       k*Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y], {y, k, Infinity}])*
    ((T + 2*L1)/(T^2*Sqrt[T + L1])) - A/T^2 + (d1*h1)/2 + c1[T]*d1 == 0;

T1 = T /. Solve[EQ1[T], T, Reals][[1]];

Table[{TCJS[T1, k], T1, k}, {k, 0.001, n, 0.001}]
SortBy[%, First][[1]]
```

I used `Table` because I know it is the fastest looping code in *Mathematica*, but it takes so much more time than matlab.

Is there any way to improve the speed?

Comment: The problem is likely the PDF's, and integrals in your definition of  `TCJS`, because these are being re evaluated every time you evaluate an entry in the table. Using `=` instead of `:=` when defining `TCJS` may help. But you'll need to make sure any parameters you don't explicitly list as inputs to the function are set before you define your function.

Comment: This code doesn't execute for me - something to do with the `Box`es. Could you give us the `InputForm` of `TCJS[T, k]` instead?

Comment: Take a look at this post on [How to copy code so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) in order to be able to provide us functional code.

Comment: We can reopen your question as soon as you fix the issues pointed out to you, as well as provide information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The code seems fixed now, thanks to m_goldberg.

Answer (score 6):

Evaluate the integral once and for all (cf. `cdfc`):

```
cdfc[k_] = 
  Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y], {y, k, Infinity}];

TCJS[T_, k_] := 
  A/T + c1[T]*d1*T + 
   h1*((d1*T)/2 + k*σ1*Sqrt[T + 1]) + (b1/T)*σ1*
    Sqrt[T + L1]*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - k*cdfc[k]);

EQ1[T_] := (k*σ1*h1)/(2*Sqrt[T + L1]) - ((b1*σ1)/
       2)*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - 
       k*cdfc[k])*((T + 2*L1)/(T^2*Sqrt[T + L1])) - 
    A/T^2 + (d1*h1)/2 + c1[T]*d1 == 0;

Table[{TCJS[T1, k], T1, k}, {k, 0.001, n, 0.001}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(*  {0.233491, Null}  *)
```

But we can extend that principal to the other functions as well, provided we block the values of `T` and `k` and use the definition of `cdfc` above:

```
Block[{T, k},

 TCJS[T_, k_] = 
  A/T + c1[T]*d1*T + 
   h1*((d1*T)/2 + k*σ1*Sqrt[T + 1]) + (b1/T)*σ1*
    Sqrt[T + L1]*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - k*cdfc[k]);

 EQ1[T_] = (k*σ1*h1)/(2*Sqrt[T + L1]) - ((b1*σ1)/
       2)*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - 
       k*cdfc[k])*((T + 2*L1)/(T^2*Sqrt[T + L1])) - 
    A/T^2 + (d1*h1)/2 + c1[T]*d1 == 0;

 ]

T1 = T /. Solve[EQ1[T], T, Reals][[1]];

murf = Table[{TCJS[T1, k], T1, k}, {k, 0.001, n, 0.001}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(*  {0.067596, Null}  *)
```